# Erro para executar programa em fortran

Tags: compilação, fortran

Preciso calcular o Minimo divisor comum em fortran, fiz o código, porém quando ele compila e roda, fecha após o usuário digitar o valor e eu não sei o que está errado.

```
PROGRAM Calc
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL :: valor,contador=0, divisao
write(*,*) "Digite um valor positivo para calcular o MDC "
read(*,*) valor
do contador = 0, valor, 1 

if(MOD(valor,contador)==0)then 
divisao=divisao+1
endif
end do

if(divisao == 2) then
    write(*,*) "O Valor digitado possui MDC"
else
    write(*,*) "O valor digitado nao possui MDC"
endif

STOP
END PROGRAM Calc
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, embora não tenha conseguido entender bem o objetivo do programa, visto que até onde lembro calculo de MDC precisa possuir no mínimo dois valores, aqui vai um código com as correções que acredito serem cabíveis:

```
PROGRAM CALC
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER*4 :: valor,contador,divisao
  WRITE(*,*) "Digite um valor inteiro positivo para calcular o MDC "
  READ(*,*)  valor
  DO contador = 1, valor, 1
    IF (MOD(valor,contador).EQ.0) THEN
      divisao=divisao+1
    END IF
  END DO
  IF (divisao .EQ. 2) THEN
    WRITE(*,*) "O Valor digitado possui MDC"
  ELSE
    WRITE(*,*) "O valor digitado nao possui MDC"
  END IF
  READ(*,*)
  STOP
END PROGRAM CALC
```

As mudanças que acredito serem relevantes são apenas duas:

1) As variáveis devem ser inteiras, pois você as utilizou no loop do comando "DO"

2) Seu loop "DO" iniciava do zero, o que fazia com que a função "MOD" capotasse. Esse era o motivo do crash que estava acontecendo.

Caso a resposta seja satisfatória, por favor, não esqueça de marcar ela para ajudar outras pessoas que estejam pesquisando algo parecido e também não esqueça de avaliar positivamente. Um abraço.

Comment: Não esqueça de sempre indentar seus códigos. Isso facilita a leitura e depuração do mesmo.